# Android - layout fields horizontally and have them line wrapped

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to perform something really simple. I'm trying to display 3 fields one after the other horizontally. I want it to be one long line but I expect it to line wrap.

Here is my simplest layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCommentText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="one very very very very very very very very very very very very long comment" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCommentUsername"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Daniel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCommentTimestamp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="1.1.1900"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

I just don't seem to succeed with this. I tried RelativeLayout and just got into even deeper trouble. Any ideas?

Comment: did you fix it? view my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#fff"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCommentText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="one very very very very very very very very very very very very long comment" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCommentUsername"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Daniel" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCommentTimestamp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="1.1.1900" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sorry, this seems not to work. I get three equal width cells in one line and the text of the comment is truncated and added with '...'

Comment: but if your string will be too long then what should you do? For that you have to remove this android:singleLine="true" line from textView